# Reporting results of linear mixed model with transformed data

Tags: mixed-model, data-transformation, reporting

How do I report results of a linear mixed model analysis if the data have been transformed? Does it still make sense to report coefficients and standard errors?

Comment: Yes, it does - but in some cases, it can be worth reporting the coefficients on the original scale, to make interpretation easier.

Comment: It's an exponential transformation. Getting the coefficients in the original scale is not easy.